# How to pass sample_weights into a Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on developing a weighted Keras model within TFX to down-weight one feature in my model that is creating fairness issues. If I'm not mistaken, I believe using sample_weights is what I'm looking for based on this documentation [enter link description here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)?

```
def _keras_model_builder():
  """Build a keras model for COMPAS dataset classification."""
  feature_columns = []
  feature_layer_inputs = {}

  for key in transformed_names(INT_FEATURE_KEYS):
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key))
    feature_layer_inputs[key] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=key)

  for key, num_buckets in zip(transformed_names(CATEGORICAL_FEATURE_KEYS),
                              MAX_CATEGORICAL_FEATURE_VALUES):
    categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity(
                key, num_buckets=num_buckets)
    feature_columns.append(
        tf.feature_column.indicator_column(categorical_column))
    feature_layer_inputs[key] = tf.keras.Input(
        shape=(1,), name=key, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)

  feature_columns_input = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
  feature_layer_outputs = feature_columns_input(feature_layer_inputs)

  dense_layers = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
      20, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='dense_1')(feature_layer_outputs)
  dense_layers = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
      10, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='dense_2')(dense_layers)
  dense_layers = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
      5, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='dense_3')(dense_layers)
  dense_layers = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(dense_layers)
  output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
      1, name='predictions')(dense_layers)

  inputs = [v for v in feature_layer_inputs.values()]
  sample_weights = tf.keras.layers.Input(
      shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32, name='race_xf')

  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,
                         sample_weights=sample_weights,
                         outputs=output)    
  model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
      optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adamax(learning_rate=_LEARNING_RATE))
  return model
```

However this code is producing the below error:

```
TypeError: ('Functional models may only specify `name` and `trainable` keyword arguments during initialization. Got an unexpected argument:', 'sample_weights')
```

This is sort of a two part question, but

1. Am I thinking about down-weighing correctly? Most docs that I've seen use the weight_column parameter within tf.estimator, which is different with Keras. [For example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/pc/exercises/fairness_text_toxicity_part1.ipynb?utm_source=practicum-fairness&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=fairnessexercise1-colab).
2. If this is the correct way to think about this, how can I correctly pass in the sample_weights parameter?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the sample_weights arguments gets passed to the fit() method of the Model, after its already been initialized (you are passing it during initialization).

Second, this is used to down-weight the significance of a any given sample to the loss function and therefore to the learning process as a whole.

There are multiple ways of "improving fairness" the simplest: drop the "unfair feature altogether".
Better yet, find engineered/combined/multiplied features that when combined/multiplied with the "unfair feature" remove the contribution of the "unfair feature" to the bias (on its own).
third: you could try and down-weight examples with the "unfair feature" but that might yield reductions in accuracy due to reduction in learning from other aspects of these examples.
I would say the second option of engineering features by multiplying them is the best if you have the time, and dropping the feature altogether is second best.
I don't think weighting is the way to go if your goal/problem is fairness. However if you have an imbalanced dataset it might be udeful to use sample_weights or Class_weights [How to set class weights for imbalanced classes in Keras?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras)